# Visual Studio 2003: 'The object is currently in use elsewhere' (the IDE, not my code)

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2003

I'm using Visual Studio 2003 working on an ASP.NET application.  Quite often, just in the middle of typing code in the Visual Studio Text Editor I get:

The following exception has occurred:
InvalidOperationException: The object is currently in use elsewhere.

This is not my code running, i'm just working in the IDE.  Sometimes it doesn't happen for maybe half an hour if i'm lucky, then I get it if I as much as move the mouse or enter one character.

Anyone know either a) what could be causing this or b) how to figure out what could be causing it?  I've tried watching with Process Monitor which has brought me no joy.  I've also tried eliminating other processes one by one (such as virus scanner etc.) but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What language are you writing in, and how big is your solution? For example, VB.Net is constantly checking for errors, and a large solution could overwhelm it.

Comment: good shout - it is actually VB.NET.  Main project has about 100 aspx pages, then there are a couple of other class library projects, maybe about 250 classes in all.

Are there options I can configure to change this background checking if this is the case?

Comment: Looks like the main option is to upgrade from VS2003

http://www.panopticoncentral.net/articles/948.aspx

Comment: Sounds like that's the problem.  I notice that it's particularly bad when I'm using the 'Properties' pane.

I am looking to get it into VS2008, it'll cure a few other things that are causing me headaches, but it's a mission critical system that's been live for 4 years so change is gonna be slow.

Cheers!